# $set and $push for multiple documents in the same mongodb update

Tags: javascript, mongodb, robo3t

I struggling to get multiple documents of the same collection updated that need to have fields added to the JSON "root", as well as a new object to an existent array called *logs*.

I'm trying this

```
db.getCollection('charges').
update({'supports.dest':ObjectId("xyz"), 
      date:{
                          $gte: new Date(2017, 11),
                          $lt: new Date(2017, 12) 
           },
      "status": {$nin : ["Captured"]  
                }
        },
      {$set: {"status": "BillingSuspended",  
           "replacedStatus":"Captured"} 
      },
      {multi:true},
      {$push : 
        {logs : {"replacedStatus" : "Captured" ,
                 date: new Date ('2017-12-13T22:00:00.000Z') 
                }
        }
      }
)
```

I'm getting this error bellow and I tried taking out the multi:true but then I loose the multi property that allows me to update many documents at the same time. I wanted a query that runs on Robomongo. I'd appreciate guys if you can help me.

**Error:**

```
[Failed to execute script.

Error: Fourth argument must be empty when specifying upsert and multi with an object. :
DBCollection.prototype._parseUpdate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:522:1
DBCollection.prototype.update@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:552:18
@(shell):1:1]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDQWw.png)

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38864917/unable-to-update-the-data-in-mongodb

Comment: Something like this should work `{
    "supports.dest":ObjectId("xyz"), 
    "date": {
      "$gte": new Date(2017, 11),
      "$lt": new Date(2017, 12)
    },
    "status": {
      "$nin": [
        "Captured"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "status": "BillingSuspended",
      "replacedStatus": "Captured"
    },
    "$push": {
      "logs": {
        "replacedStatus": "Captured",
        "date": new Date ('2017-12-13T22:00:00.000Z')
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "multi": true
  }`

Comment: Thanks @Veeram! it worked!

Comment: another question I have is how to pass to the "replacedStatus" field not the status "Captured", but dynamically the status that the charge had before the update, do you know what I mean?

Answer (score 7):

You have to try like this

```
db.getCollection('charges').updateMany(
        {
            'supports.dest': ObjectId("xyz"),
            'date': {
                '$gte': new Date(2017, 11),
                '$lt': new Date(2017, 12)
            },
            "status": {
                $nin: ["Captured"]
            }
        },
        {
            $set: {
                "status": "BillingSuspended",
                "replacedStatus": "Captured"
            },
            $push: {
                logs: {
                    "replacedStatus": "Captured",
                    date: new Date('2017-12-13T22:00:00.000Z')
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: you can approve my answer

Comment: there is already a deprecation warning for update and prompts the use of updateMany or updateOne. Were you able to update many with push? In the docu, there is no push. Thanks.

Comment: @Woppi for which mongo version it is depreciated ?

Comment: Still there: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/#operators